# Problems with Fujitsu SAS hard drive on Intel server

Tags: raid

I have a [Intel S5000VSA server](http://www.intel.com/p/en_US/support/highlights/server/s5000vsa) with two Fujitsu 250 GB SAS hard drives. My Windows installation was damaged and I couldn't boot my server with Live Windows.

Now I want boot them with RAID card on my home PC because I want access to my files.

My first question is about a port on RAID card with PIMB name and I don't know about it also I don't see this port on any motherboard. What is this?

My second question is about recover my files, what solution do you suggest?

Comment: Could you add some information? 0) What happened if you try to boot the damaged windows installation? (which error message?) 1) Which RAID card is used? 2) Which format (e.g mirror or stripe. Mirror would be a safe guess, but only a guess).